# Cannot connect Segmented Control to its IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4, ios6

I have created a segmented control in the interface builder.

In my ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
@property IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment;
- (IBAction)switchMode:(id)sender;
@end
```

What I could do was to connect the Segmented Control with the IBAction but I cannot connect it with the IBOutlet!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add a segmented control to the nib/Storyboard
- Add the following code into the .h

`@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment;`

- In your storyboard or xib make sure that the files owner has the same classname as that of the class in which you written the outlet
- Right click on the segmantControl and a window with outlets and actions appears
- click and drag on the **referencing outlet**  and drop it on the **filesowner** a new pop appears which includes your outlet written in code select it .

Connection established

Comment: The Issue was that I didn't drag it to the appropraite ViewController! In fact I had to create a new ViewController which inherited from UIViewController. In the Storyboard I changed the custom class to the new ViewController and then I was able to drag it!

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to write parameters of property, correct it like below code

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *Segment;
```

after this synthesize this property in .m file like this

```
@Synthesize Segment;
```

Comment: @RavindraBagale you do not need parameters for properties, it will just use defaults, also synthesizing (or not synthesizing) would not prevent being able to setup an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that with some xCode update you can no longer connect certain outlets to your .h. You should be fine connecting it in your .m though:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedController;
@end
```

I will read some docs and see when this changed. Also there really is no reason to connect this property to your public interface (hence why it is no longer allowed). Only the View Controller of that class should have control over it.

Comment: Well, I still dont know how I connect the actual object from the interface builder to the Object in the ViewController?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the assistant editor and just control drag from the UISegmentedController into your .m interface (you do not even need to type the @property stuff). Then when you see a line appear just let go and type the info in there you need. It will create the property for you. Then access it in your code with `self.mySegmentedController`

Comment: I have read that on other pages but the truth is this line never appears! I am sure that I am in the assistant editor and I clicked on the segmented Control + ctrl and pull a line to the .m viewController but no Line appears

Comment: Same issue with a basic label!

Comment: make sure you are dragging it between `@interface ViewController()` and `@end` **NOT** `@implementation ViewController` and `@end` if the `@interface...` is not there, then add it. `ViewController` is the name of your class.

Comment: Is your view controller set as the customer class of the file owner in the nib?